# Python Radio Button Not Showing Up?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, radio-button

I'm follow a GUI through Python tutorial on YouTube, and I cannot get the radio buttons show up in the message box and it works fine for the author of the video. I get no error message, is there a piece of my code that is incorrect or what am I doing wrong?

```
#create radio buttons; input equal to a value of a string and will come up checked
dayStatus = StringVar()
dayStatus.set(None)
radio1 = Radiobutton(app, text="I'm feeling good", value="I'm feeling good", variable = dayStatus, command=beenClicked).pack
#clicked radio calls the been clicked command
radio1 = Radiobutton(app, text="I'm feeling crummy", value="I'm feeling crummy", variable = dayStatus, command=beenClicked).pack

button1 = Button(app, text="Click Here", width=20,command=changeLabel)
button1.pack(side='bottom',padx=15,pady=15)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct these two lines by adding braces () at the end of the lines:

```
radio1 = Radiobutton(app, text="I'm feeling good", value="I'm feeling good", variable = dayStatus, command=beenClicked).pack()
radio1 = Radiobutton(app, text="I'm feeling crummy", value="I'm feeling crummy", variable = dayStatus, command=beenClicked).pack()
```

Comment: Pfft, always missing something simple--that's me! Hey, thanks so much! Gave you an upvote! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :-)